# LoadImage(byteArray) doesnt work on unity

Tags: c#, image, firebase, unity-game-engine

```
 void fotogetir2()
{
    Firebase.Storage.FirebaseStorage storage = Firebase.Storage.FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;

    Firebase.Storage.StorageReference storage_ref = storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("------ url ------");
    const long maxAllowedSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    storage_ref.GetBytesAsync(maxAllowedSize).ContinueWith((Task<byte[]> task) => {
        if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
            // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
        }
        else
        {
            byte[] fileContents = task.Result;
            Debug.Log("Finished downloading!");


            Debug.Log("texture created !!" + fileContents.Length);


            Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
            Debug.Log("texture created !!" + fileContents.Length);
            Debug.Log("texture rendered !!");
              texture.LoadImage(fileContents);  //  clogged here !!!!!!!!!!!!!
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = texture;
            if (texture != null)
            {
                Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
                im.sprite = sprite;
            }

            Debug.Log("image loaded !!");




        }
    });
}
```

my function all is here anyone help me ? what do ı wrong? 
I want to show a picture from the firebase storage link. I connect to storage and convert it to byte array. I want to write byte array on texture and export it as an image. but I couldn't write on the texture.

Comment: What happens when you run your code and how is it different to what you want to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem, just move define process out of scope. Sometimes look and see different things..
If anything you want to ask, I will help as much as I can.on comments..

```
void fotoGetir(string url)
{
    Firebase.Storage.FirebaseStorage storage = Firebase.Storage.FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;
    byte[] fileContents=null;
    Firebase.Storage.StorageReference storage_ref = storage.GetReferenceFromUrl(url);
    const long maxAllowedSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    storage_ref.GetBytesAsync(maxAllowedSize).ContinueWithOnMainThread((Task<byte[]> task) =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
            // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
        }
        else
        {
          fileContents = task.Result;
            Debug.Log("Finished downloading!");

        }
        byte[] fotoBytes;
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
        if(fileContents != null) { 
        texture.LoadImage(fileContents);
            Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
            soruImage.sprite = sprite;
        }


    });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `ContinueWith` with `ContinueWithOnMainThread`. You're doing a lot of work in the `UnityEngine` namespace from a background thread, which can get sketchy.

If you were following along from [my video tutorial](https://youtu.be/JAaCUmQ6LBo?t=460), this is why I used coroutines.

If that works, feel free to read my [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/07/firebase-and-tasks-how-to-deal-with.html) or watch [my video](https://youtu.be/5GzFDXvZxKM) on threading in Unity for more information about what's going on and what your other options are.

--Patrick

Comment: thanx! your video helped me :)